# Can NLog store the current Thread user

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I am using NLog to provide all my logging, do you know if it is possible to store the current Thread user details, by changing the NLog.Config file?

Comment: You may want to add some tags, e.g. ".net" and maybe a reference to the language you're interested in ("c#"?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go: `${windows-identity}`